# HABTM and retrieving all Model A that does not has certain Model B

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have 3 tables: `users`, `specialities`, `specialities_users`.

```
User HABTM Speciality
Speciality HABTM User
SpecialitiesUser belongsTo Speciality,User
```

I have also model `SpecialitiesUser`.

When I want to get specialities for given user I can do it through

```
SpecialitiesUser->find('all' array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $given_user_id));
```

Now I want to get all specialities that user NOT belongs to. How I can do this in Cake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$other_specialities` variable in the following code should be what you want:

```
$the_users_specialities = $this->SpecialitiesUser->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'SpecialitiesUser.user_id' => $given_user_id
    ),
    'fields' => 'SpecialitiesUser.speciality_id'
));

$other_specialities = $this->Speciality->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOT' => array(
            'Speciality.id' => $the_users_specialities
        )
    )
));
```

**UPDATE:** This is how to do it using a single query:

```
$db = $this->Speciality->getDataSource();

$sub_query = $db->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields' => array('`SpecialitiesUser`.`speciality_id`'),
        'table' => $db->fullTableName($this->SpecialitiesUser),
        'alias' => 'SpecialitiesUser',
        'conditions' => array('`SpecialitiesUser`.`user_id`' => $given_user_id),
    ),
    $this->Speciality
);

$other_specialities = $this->Speciality->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        $db->expression('`Speciality`.`id` NOT IN (' . $sub_query . ')')
    )
));
```

Comment: This works but I want it in a single query - it is possible with nested SELECT but I don't know how to do this in cake...